# mysql tables strange behaviour

Tags: mysql, wordpress, autoincrement

i have a wordpress driven web site. i am having a very very weird issue. i am clean installing my wordpress, using it about a week or so then i am losing admin rights in wp-admin. i can login with my admin account, i can confirm that its role is still admin but for example i cant post a new page. i am asking this here cause i believe this is not related with wordpress. i am having a very strange problem with my mysql database. i dont know how but i believe after a period of time my tables loses their auto increment functionality. cause this is not only a admin account related problem. for example after this thing happens, nobody can register to my site, no body can post etc. please help me. i am trying to fix this issue about 2 months. because i dont really understand what happens, i cant find a real solution. how can i debug this for example? thanks

Comment: Have you looked in the mysql logs (what OS are you running on), or your web server error logs?

Comment: i am on ubuntu 10.04 lts and using nginx as webserver. how can i look mysql logs. where are they?

Comment: You can find your mysql error logs by logging into your mysql server and running `show global variables like 'log_error';`

Answer (score 0):

typically, this tends to occur when mysql's run out of disk space. how large is the database, what does df -h report, etc.?

you may want to consider posting the my.cnf as well, though i'm fairly certain this is a disk space/fs quota issue based purely on the symptoms you mention.

Comment: `Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda              20G  735M   18G   4% /
devtmpfs              249M  112K  249M   1% /dev
none                  249M     0  249M   0% /dev/shm
none                  249M   40K  249M   1% /var/run
none                  249M     0  249M   0% /var/lock
none                  249M     0  249M   0% /lib/init/rw
` and this is my.cnf http://pastebin.com/0rviE4k7